# Asp.Net Core 1.0 and SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, asp.net-core, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

We are working on Asp.Net Core 1.0 application, and we would like to display SSRS reports from the application but unfortunately SSRS is not supported in Asp.Net Core 1.0, may any one help with this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an object to the html page which holds the SSRS report viewer, you then hard code the path of the report in the "data":

```
<object 
    data="http://ServerName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fFolderName%2fReportName&rs:Command=Render"
    width="100%" 
    height="800px">
</object>
```

Comment: The Asp.Net Core 1.0 application will not allow to add aspx page at all, it is MVC.

Comment: Can you host a pure html page and put that object into the body?